# forcing black and white printing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I need to print the contents between two div tags. The printing is done fine, but somehow if the user checks the "Background Graphics" checkbox in the printing pop up then the background becomes blue which is the actual background color of the web page. Is it possible to force the user to print only in black and white or disable the "Background Graphics" checkbox from the pint pop up? Below is the image of the "Background Graphics" check box that I am talking about:

[image]

below is my code to do the printing:

```
<script>

        function printContent(el) {
               var restorepage = $('body').html();
               document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();
       
               document.getElementById('<%=acrLogo.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById('<%=compName.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
               var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();
               printcontent.removeAttr('style');
                $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
                window.print();
                $('body').html(restorepage);
            }

</script>
```

I also tried putting this in the page:

```
 <style>
article {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
}

</style>
```

Below is my div tag:

```
<div>
 The contents needs to be printed. This is just a test.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried a printer-specific style sheet which hides the blue background altogether? E.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use grayscale filter on @media print:

```css
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Like this:

```css
@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
Print this!
<span style="color:red;">Red text</span> 
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

It'll force it:

[image: forced b/w printing]

Comment: This is the code, I am looking for. The only issue is, I am not trying to print the entire page. I am only trying to print what is inside the div tags. I also have a label control  inside the div tag and I set the value to that label to current date and time and make it visible in javascript so not sure how can that be done with @media print. any help will be appreciated.